# When internet shutdown data should autometticlly save

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

how can i design a form so that the data users enter into it is automatically saved to SharePoint, without clicking Submit,

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with the question title? Are you using Infopath with SharePoint online?  Do you want to save automatically when the internet connection is lost? How would that be possible??

Comment: So my question is can we set any functionality or action that if we lost connection that whatever we fill in fields saved automatically or maybe when we get the connection back, get all lost data. something like that

Comment: So, are you using Infopath with SharePoint online??? That would be really weird in this day and age.

Comment: I am using InfoPath with Sharepoint online. Weird?? so which is better one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to reconsider you choice of tool. InfoPath will not be supported for much longer. That was announced years ago. The supported tool for online forms is PowerApps, which is included in  most Office 365 and SharePoint online plans. With PowerApps you can run apps offline on mobile devices.

See

https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/build-offline-apps-with-new-powerapps-capabilities/

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/offline-apps

Comment: Thanks You !!!!!